# Does AWS ECS Control Plane i.e Cluster cost any thing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-eks

On looking at the EKS Pricing page, its very clear that the cluster i.e control plane as of today costs $.10/hour. Quote from - https://aws.amazon.com/eks/pricing/

> You pay $0.10 per hour for each Amazon EKS cluster that you create.

But on looking at ECS pricing page - https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/pricing/, I am not able to figure out the cluster i.e control plane cost. So before creating an ECS cluster and leaving it there irrespective of usage, I want to know how I will be billed.

Please share your thoughts!!!!

Also, my understanding is, for EKS cluster, I will be charged for the cluster irrespective of the usage i.e the cluster is used for deployments/pods/services etc or just left doing nothing. Please correct if wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ECS does not have a control plane/cluster fee. You only pay for the EC2 or Fargate resources ECS runs your containers on.

Your understanding about the EKS cluster costs is correct.

---

Note: There are other fees an ECS cluster can generate, such as CloudWatch Logs and Metrics fees, but that's true for all the AWS compute services, including EKS, Elastic Beanstalk, Lambda, etc.